# are destructors necessary in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a concern. I'm a first year student of computer science. Normally I'm very inquisitive in class but, not always my teacher has an answer, or not always knows the answer. Are destructors necessary in C#? What I mean is if I have to implement a destructor method as I normally do with constructors, is it a good practice or i can avoid it and the garbage collector will do it for me?

Comment: Depends on if your object has managed resources or not (open files, sockets, other objects that require explicit cleanup).

Comment: C# is a garbage collected language. You don't need to worry about cleaning up after yourself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Destructors (or finalizers) are good to have in the language - but you should almost *never* use them. Basically you should only need them if you have a *direct* handle on an unmanaged resource, and not only is that incredibly rare, but using [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a tiny level of indirection is a better idea anyway (which handles clean-up for you). See [Joe Duffy's blog post on the topic](http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/12/27/never-write-a-finalizer-again-well-almost-never/) for more details.

For what it's worth, I can't remember the last time I wrote a finalizer other than to test some odd behaviour or other.

For the vast majority of the time, life is simpler:

- The garbage collector can handle memory resource cleanup
- If you use an unmanaged resource (e.g. a file) locally within a method, use a `using` statement to make sure you release it when you're done with it
- If you need a reference to an unmanaged resource (or anything else which implements `IDisposable`) as an *instance variable* within your type, your type should itself implement `IDisposable`. (I try to avoid this where possible. Even when it *is* necessary, you can make life simpler by making your class `sealed`, at which point you at least don't need to worry about other subclasses having even more unmanaged state to clean up.)

Comment: "If you need a reference to an unmanaged resource", do you refer to a 'direct' reference to an unmanaged resource?

Comment: @Pingpong: No, it doesn't have to be direct - typically if it's indirect, you fall into the "or anything else which implements IDisposable" category.

Comment: That is what I want to double check. Is it correct that the 3rd point includes two scenarios: direct unmanged resources (those that have no `IDisposable`), and those that implements `IDisposable`?  They are confusing.

Comment: Double check: On 3rd point, even using `sealed`, the class has to implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: @Pingpong: If you want to be able to dispose them, yes. The only difference that being sealed makes is that you can use a simpler pattern: you don't need to worry about subclasses potentially needing to tidy-up as well.

Comment: Please answer question on my second comment.  I guess it is a yes.

Comment: Whether they're unmanaged or managed, assuming your object "owns" them, you should implement IDisposable and clean up (whether that's calling Dispose or something more involved) when Dispose is called. So it's not really two different scenarios - just different implementation details for the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

No destructors are not neccesary in C#. The reason why that's true is that in C# the memory is managed automatically and you haven't to do anything except from creating an object. When the garbage collector verifies that an object is not referred anywhere else in your application, then it reclaims its memory, without having you declared any destructor for this object, like we do on C++ for instance.

Comment: Ah, and no mention of IDisposable. Sorry o say, but memory managed does not help with unmanaged resources.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think that's a good practice to write unmanaged code in C#, but as I am aware of-I might be wrong- that we have the option to write unmanaged code in C#.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios: Are you thinking of *unsafe* code perhaps? There may be specialist environments converting C# into unmanaged code, but I'm not immediately aware of any. And even if you're writing unsafe code and/or have members with unmanaged resource handles, using SafeHandle avoids the need for finalizers.

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed this portion of my post. Thank you ! I wanted to refer to unsafe code, which is not associated with unmanaged.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios: Righto, glad we've cleared up the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is unnecessary in any language. They serve their purpose.

Destructors will destruct the object and you'll end up with object resurrection.(*If you try to access destructed object, you might get an error*)

GC will automatically do this for you when the object has no longer any references to it. So there's is no need for you to do this explicitly..

Also, implementing `IDisposable` should be given preference over destructor.