# Can anyone give a real time example on how is Destructors used?

Tags: c#, class, oop, destructor

I was learning Destructors, when I got a question -> When do we need to use destructors? and also at the same time, I was like Thinking on How these can be used in real life.

So Can anyone give a real time example on how is Destructors used?

Comment: Do you mean `Finalizers` or `Dispose`?

Comment: I would suggest editing your post to use "real life" everywhere - because "real time" has a very different meaning.

Comment: I meant in where can we use in real life.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good article by Eric Lippert. This is about finalizer/destructor and it has some tests. [One of the test says](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/):

> When finalizers are being run because a process is being shut down,
> the runtime sets a limit on how much time the finalizer thread gets to
> spend making a good-faith effort to run all the finalizers. If that
> limit is exceeded then the runtime **simply stops running more
> finalizers and shuts down the program**

So it can be concluded that finalizers can be avoided to be written almost on all cases.

Read more about finalizer [by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23026910/1646240):

> You should almost never use them. Basically you should only need them if you have a direct handle on an
> unmanaged resource, and not only is that incredibly rare, but using
> SafeHandle as a tiny level of indirection is a better idea anyway
> (which handles clean-up for you)